# Populate wordpress menu with link to custom field value (file download)

Tags: custom-field, menus

I have an additional menu that appears on some single.php pages. To this menu I would like to add an li with a link to a PDF which is uploaded to the post by a custom field (advanced custom fields helps with this).

I found a snippet on how to add todays date to my menu, and thought I could maybe use this as a starting point. However I´m not good enough coder to know where to go from here. I would appreciate some help with it!

This is the snippet I´m starting with:
http://pastebin.com/xHHxuHdQ

I need to make it display this instead:

```
<a href="<?php the_field('mcf_uppsagning-pdf'); ?>">Uppsägning</a>
```

I cant just replace it though and I dont know the syntax enough to know how to modify it. Please help :)

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar requirement so I just ended up writing a custom walker - works a treat, and is fairly easy to do.

Comment: @JohanDahl Please go through your solved Questions and mark answers as solved.

Comment: `the_field()` is a function provided by the custom fields plugin mentioned and I thought the below approach was easiest to use as writing a custom walker isn't really that easy for beginners!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Filter wp_nav_menu() to add additional links and other output
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_pdf_to_menu', 10, 2);
function add_pdf_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'extra-menu')  {

        $pdf = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mcf_uppsagning-pdf', true );
        if ( $pdf )
            $items .=  '<li><a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $pdf ) .  '">Uppsägning</a></li>';

    }
    return $items;
}
```

Essentially because you're in the context of the single page `get_the_ID()` will return the id for the post/page you're on. If that doesn't work try using `get_queried_object_id()` in place of `get_the_ID()`.

EDIT:
changed the above code to return the attachment permalink.

Comment: Hmm, sadly that doesn´t display anything for me.

Comment: That comment was not finished, sry for accidently posting it.

It almost works now! This did add a link with the correct title, but the link is only /145. That is the ID of the attachment. I need to get the URL, but it should only be a slight change should it not?

Also, if I might add another question. Is there a way to decide where in the menu this new li will be inserted?

Thanks you.

Comment: @JohanDahl I updated the code example - you can pass any attachment ID into `wp_get_attachment_url()` and it'll give you the URL

Comment: @JohanDahl to change the order of the links you'd need to do some clever stuff with the `$items` string. Is it a simple case like putting it at the top or do you need in the middle somewhere?

Comment: It works now! Thank´s a ton =)

The link should be somewhere in the middle, hehe. But it actually doesn´t matter that much and it needs to be easy to change because it´s not set in stone yet. So if it´s a complicated thing then I´ll just skip it!

Comment: @Johan Dahl: You have a 0% answer acceptance rate; you should go back to your old questions and accept correct answers or submit your own answers. That's the way this site works.

Comment: @songdogtech: I´m sorry about that I did not see where you check correct answers. But I see now, and I will do that.